# set local_lock when mounting volume via NFS on Kubernetes

Tags: nfs, kubernetes

If I have a volume that mounts via nfs, provisioned with the nfs client provisioner from kubernetes incubator repo, how can I mount the volume with `local_lock=posix` instead of `local_lock=none`?

When I view the mounted directory from the pod, it shows

```
nfshost:/srv/K8sFast/consumer-pod-pvc-4fdd3eef-9337-11ea-a4e5-caa934b40d56 on /config type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.0.10.1,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.8.4)
```

But I need that `local_lock` to be `posix` instead to allow locking.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#persistentvolumespec-v1-core), `PersistentVolume` objects support a `mountOptions: ["local_lock=posix"]`